# Having one "base" formula re-used in and updating other cells

Tags: google-apps-script, excel-formula, google-sheets, formulas

Here's a tough one to explain. Tough one to wrap your head around.

I have a column of formulas that, when updated, should change the formulas of other columns.

For example, you have the below spreadsheet:

[image]

When you copy column A, and paste it to column D, the formulas would respectively change to =D1+1, =D1*5, etc. That's great. But now I want to change for example cell A2, from =A1+1 to =A1+9. How can I get the rest of the cells to change from e.g. =B1+1 to =B1+9.

How can I "link" one cell's formula to another cell's formula? How can there be a "base" or "primary" or "master" cell which other cell's reference for their formulas, and all "slave" cells change dynamically when the "master" cell changes?

Putting =A2 in cell B2 wouldn't work since I'm not copying/pasting values, but trying to get the base formula updated automatically, but still changed dynamically for it's own respective column.

Ideally, this is done with a formula, not a script, and all on the same sheet.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
A2 = column1+1
D2 = =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"column",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",""),1))
```

The thought here is to replace the word "column" with the letter of the column the formula is in, then convert that to a working formula. Except the outcome as it is spits out D1+1 which is SO CLOSE, that's what I want! But it's a string, not a formula

Comment: put your constant in another cell and refer to that cell with an absolute reference: `=A1+$Z$1` now when you drag it over the reference to Z1 stays and the reference to A1 will change.  then all you need to do is change Z1

Comment: Though while this would work for dragging or copying/pasting, this wouldn't update all existing columns' formulas to mirror the master. So of the formula for the master was "take the 1 cell above this cell, add 2, multiply it by the cell to the right by 3", copying and pasting that put works fine. But of you want to say "... multiply it by the cell to the right by 4" (instead of 3), how would all those other cells get automatically updated? Or, "... take the 2 cells above this cell..." instead of "the 1 cell above this cell"

Comment: Use `INDIRECT` with your string? Note that lots of `INDIRECT` are going to tank spreadsheet performance since every one of them gets re-evaluated after any change to the entire spreadsheet

Comment: @tehhowch I haven't yet played with INDIRECT, but that's a good point about performance. Each year I'd add about 300 additional references to their respective base formulas, is that too many INDIRECTS? I'm not even sure what an INDIRECT formula would look like yet, but I'll play around with it

Answer (score 1):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:D1+1)
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Wouldn't this require putting the formula "to be calculated" in all of the columns? What if the formula in the "base" cell changed from "=(A1+1)*(B1+2)" to "=(A1+1)*(B4+2)"? Then all the other cells based on this same "base" formula should change their formula to reference row 4 instead of row 1 for the respective column (the column after the cell the formula is in), and do so automatically/dynamically. So really no calculable formula should be in the "slave" cells, only references to the "master" cell, but use the new respective columns

Comment: Thanks! I just played with ARRAYFORMULA for an hour, hadn't used it before. One issue I'm having, is that my columns are not next to each other. I have 5 columns for each customer I'm working on. Arrayformula looks like it'd work, but I'd need to the output of the arrayformula to be inserted every 5th column. Is that possible?

Comment: Best I've come up with, it's ugly: multiple IF statements inside an ARRAYFORMULA, and just put in the cell of the first column, takes care of the rest
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:L1="Start Date",(A2:L2+1)*(A2:L2+2),IF(A1:L1="End Date",(A2:L2+2)*(A2:L2+3),IF(A1:L1="Status",(A2:L2+3)*(A2:L2+4),IF(A1:L1="Completed Date",(A2:L2+4)*(A2:L2+5),"")))))

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind this won't work, one of the 5 columns is a "Status" column of which I need to edit/maintain. This breaks the ArrayFormula since there's an input where it expects a blank cell

Comment: Bummer, so it sounds like Arrays are out. Thanks for your help tho! I liked learning about Arrays. Back to square one for now :/ Unless I can figure out how to make this actually calculate: ="="&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"column",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1",""))